# Is there a way in grafana to get number of requests at a given time instance?

Tags: devops, grafana, monitoring

I have one endpoint for which I would like to see number of requests at a given time (not period). For instance, how many requests were received at 9.30 a.m.

The function I believe I can make use of might be: `echo_requests_total`, but it just accumulates the count and if I try increase() or rate() functions even those do not produce the expected output, which is obvious.

I am not even sure about what I want is even possible or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `echo_requests_total` is, but if it follows Prometheus convention on metric names - it is counter.

For counters "value at given time" (at least in described sense) is not really an option. Its value is number of requests made between previous reset (most likely restart) and current moment.

If you want to see number of requests made during some sensible period (like 1 minute) you can use query like `echo_requests_total - echo_requests_total offset 1m`.

In case of Grafana this value will be calculated for the end of dashboard time window.

AFAIK, there is now possibility to pin single panel to some half-fixed time (like 9.30 am of yesterday): you can shift it (either by using query like `echo_requests_total offset 1h - echo_requests_total offset 1h1m`, or by using panel's option > Query options > Timeshift). Or you can pin you date to some fixed timestamp: `echo_requests_total @ 123412343214` where `123412343214` is unix timestamp.

**DISCLAIMER**: it is entirely possible, that through some elaborate logic (9.30 am of yesterday) is achievable by combing `@ timestamp` and Grafana  variables, but I have no grasp of how it could be done.